# Going through all arguments given and checking their values

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, arguments

I am pretty new to Python and I tried to make a simple program.
I tried to define a function that takes any given number of arguments and prints all even numbers given.
However, I do not know how to know how many numbers were given, and mostly how to go through them, or more precisely, how to make a loop that checks each of them. Thanks in advance!

This is my bad code :

```
def even_number_filter(*arg):
    a = len(sys.argv)
    for (arg % 2 == 0):
    print ("\n%d is an even number") % arg

even_number_filter (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Comment: Take a look at [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over `arg` itself, it is simply a tuple of the arguments

```
def even_number_filter(*arg):
    for i in arg:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            print('{} is an even number'.format(i))

>>> even_number_filter(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
2 is an even number
4 is an even number
6 is an even number
8 is an even number
10 is an even number
```

For future reference, however, I would discourage this kind of design. Instead I would simply accept some sequence directly such as a `list` or `tuple`

Comment: Thank you very much. By the way, how did you edit my post so quickly? you edited it literaly 10 seconds after i finished.

Answer (score 2):

To do this using set & list comprehension:

```
print {x for x in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} if x % 2 == 0}
print [x for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] if x % 2 == 0]
```

Produces:

```
set([8, 2, 4, 10, 6])
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Where possible you should try to use comprehension (or generators) over explicit for loops.  Not so important as you are just starting out and trying to learn the basics but good to start off with good habits!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, take the arguments as an iterable (a list or a generator) rather than varargs. Then, this is the ideal time to use a list comprehension:

```py
def even_numbers(numbers):
    return [
        num for num in numbers
        if num % 2 == 0
    ]


def even_number_filter(numbers):
    for num in even_numbers(numbers):
        print "{0} is even".format(num)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    even_number_filter(range(10))

0 is even
2 is even
4 is even
6 is even
8 is even
```